# Fix creases on a curved surface

Tags: shadows

Basically I am working on an aircraft and I had to cut out the windows (I use the Knife Project tool )

But I have these weird shadows/creases. 
I know the topology is terrible but this is a quick project and I am not so advanced yet.

Thanks in advance.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Having a proper topology would help a lot here, but beyond that maybe try increasing the subdivision of the body surface a little, before knife projecting. An *Edge Split* modifier may also help if you don't have one yet.

Answer (score -1):

These are nearly impossible to fix.  However, beveling the edges of the windows should help.