# Creases when cutting aircraft windows

Tags: objects

I need help, 
I need to cut windows out of the fuselage of an airliner, however every time I do that I get these weird shadows/creases.
I am limited to a certain amount of vertices because it is for a Flight Simulator, and it is also important the windows stay at the right size, which they are now.

Thanks in advance :)

[image: a busy cat]

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: If polygon count matter as you said, I would warn you that those N-Gons around the windows are hiding lots of triangular faces (that's where the shading came from BTW: long and thin tris...). It really depends on your target software, but usually the triangular mesh should be taken into account, so I would extrinsecate the "real" geometry and then optimizate from there..

Comment: The mesh is triangulated although I didn't apply the modifier.

Comment: It's impossible to resolve with current number of faces and vertices, you'll need to add at least one top to bottom loop cut and proceed to insets and bevels around those windows. If polycount is that important paint a texture of windows and use it as an alpha mask which allows skipping any geometry cnanges at all (the software you export to has to have alpha textures support for that)..

Comment: What do you mean by "mesh is triangulated"? Maybe I was not clear: I wanted to suggest the idea of converting the n-gons in tris (or quads, it depends on your need) so you'll be able to adjust the topology in order to achieve a correct shading.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66928/fix-creases-on-a-curved-surface and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76037/how-to-avoid-mesh-anomalies-after-knife-project